# Как сделать скриншот/видео отдельной области Android?

Tags: java, android, screenshots, vlc

имеется приложение, в нём реализован показ видео через VLC library (Media Player), видео проигрывается через RTSP поток. Требуется по нажатию кнопки (условно "Take screenshot") снять скриншот именно с проигрывателя видео в реальном качестве а не скриншот всей страницы.
Так же требуется подобным методом снять видео с этого же проигрывателя, например при нажатии на кнопку (условно "Take video") начинается запись объекта и при повторном нажатии запись заканчивается и кладётся в галерею телефона пользователя.
Если есть какие мысли и варианты решения куда копать, помогите пожалуйста.

[Github: Используемый lib VLC](https://github.com/pedroSG94/vlc-example-streamplayer)